# Why does notification show on simulator but not actual iphone? (flutter_local_notifications)

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to implement notifications for my flutter app, but it only worked on simulator. When used with an actual iPhone, it didn't work at all. Here is my code:

```
Future<void> initNotification() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_ac_unit');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsiOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsiOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

Future<void> showNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, int seconds) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'main_channel',
          'Main Channel',
          channelDescription: 'Main channel notifications',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.max,
          icon: '@drawable/ic_ac_unit',
        ),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'default.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        ),
      ),
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );
  }
```

I call both of these in the Init of my main file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [haveyou ddone the ios setup correctly?](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#general-setup)

Comment: I have already added if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
} Was there anything else I missed?